# How to delete the contents of a UITextField programmatically?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am writing an iPhone app that has a number of UITextFields that requires the user to input a bunch of data. I would like to have a simple 'delete' facility that allows the user to discard any data they have put in to the multiple fields.

I've been struggling with this issue for a few days now. I can't seem to find a way of reaching into the individual text fields and changing the text. My app throws errors at me no matter what I try.

Comment: Yes, I created the fields in IB

Comment: Have you made IBOutlets to the text fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of tackling this.

You can write code to wipe each of them individually.  To do this, you create an `IBOutlet` for each one, and assign a blank string to their `text` properties.  If you only have a couple of fields, that's simplest.  If you have more, it's not so good.

You can make them all children of a common container view and loop over its subviews.  That way, you only need to hook up a single `IBOutlet`.

You can recurse over your entire view hierarchy and blank out all the text fields you find.

Another approach, which isn't very well documented by Apple, is to use an `IBOutletCollection`.  That way, you can assign all of your text fields to the one `IBOutletCollection` and loop over it.  This is probably the simplest, most straightforward way of doing it.

Comment: Just got back from watching new Transformers movie... When the girl suggests to go see an action movie, you don't say no! :) I used the IBOutletCollection method you described and it worked wonders and with one line of code. I declared an array and linked all my text fields to it in IB. I simply referenced the array in an action sheet and set one of the buttons to [inputData setValue:(nil) forKey:@"text"]. Simple when you know how! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just assign tags to each textfield in a sequence using tag property in interface builder and then get the textField like this

```
UITextField *txtf = (UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:aTagValue];

txtf.text = @""; or nil;
```