# Screen Saving on iOS

Tags: ios, text, camera

I am developing a simple camera app, where when you hit a button, text comes on the screen above the user's head (which is seen via the Camera).

When the app is exited and reopened (NOT force quit), the text is still there.

How do I get the app to "start fresh" each time?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you do anything in [`applicationWillEnterForeground:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillEnterForeground:) (for example, clearing the text)?

Comment: @thegrinner I can't find applicationWillEnterForeground EDIT: I just searched the project, and nothing came up...

Comment: It's part of the UIApplicationDelegate protocol. You implement it in your app delegate. It's an optional method, so it isn't there by default.

Comment: What should I do then? (I am a newbie, sorry!) @thegrinner

Comment: I'd recommend having a refresh/reset method in the ViewController that displays the text. Then, add `applicationWillEnterForeground:` to your app delegate and have it call the refresh/reset method on said view controller.

Comment: Another option would be to look at the lifecycle methods for the view - you could probably clear the text in [`viewWillAppear`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear:). Now that I think of it, this might be the better approach if you always want to have the view cleared of text when it appears.

Comment: Do you by chance have code that I could put into Xcode, like I said, I am a newbie, so I have no idea what to put into viewWillAppear. PS: I know where viewWillAppear is. @thegrinner

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the text in [`viewWillAppear`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#/apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear%3a). For example, if we assume the text is in a `UILabel` called `overlayLabel`:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // Don't forget to call super's viewWillAppear! I generally do this before
    // doing anything unique to this control
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Set the text to an empty string
    overlayLabel.text = @"";

    // Do anything else you need to when the view appears.
}
```

Comment: Hmm... doesn't work. The text is still showing. If it makes a difference, it isn't a UILabel, it's a UITextView. Is there something else I need to add?

Comment: @Branch You tried assigning a blank string to the text property of your UITextView? Similar to the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560888/how-to-delete-the-contents-of-a-uitextfield-programmatically)?

Comment: I used the code you posted, (I did change overlayLabel to the name of my label). I wonder what I am missing. @thegrinner

Comment: @Branch If you put a breakpoint in `viewWillAppear`, is it triggering? How did you declare the UITextView?

Comment: I don't know how to put a break point, and what do you mean by declare? @thegrinner Sorry I am so new to this!

Comment: when I use the code above, it only clears after a force quit, or on the first launch.