# How to clear the Entered textfield when the user taps on the button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, uitextfield

i am working on the Registration form , after filling multiple textfields when the user taps on the button the textfield should be clear.

Comment: show your tried code,

Comment: if you want to clear all textfields or else particular textfield

Comment: i want to clear all textfields

Comment: when i tap on the button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete the contents of a UITextField programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560888/how-to-delete-the-contents-of-a-uitextfield-programmatically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**swift**

create the **IBOutletCollections** or add **all your textfield to one array** for e.g

```
 @IBOutlet var storeAllTexts: [UITextField]!
```

on your button action method, call the following

```
   storeAllTexts.forEach { $0.text = "" }
```

**objective C**

create the **IBOutletCollections**

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UITextField) NSArray *storeAllTexts;
```

on your button action

```
 for (UITextField *getCurrentText in self.storeAllTexts) {
  getCurrentText.text = @"";
}
```

for sample your get the [SO duplicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836930/how-can-i-use-iboutletcollection-to-connect-multiple-uiimageviews-to-the-same-ou)

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use UITextField collection, you can use this,

```
@IBAction func buttontapped(_ sender: Any) {
    self.view.subviews.forEach({ item in
        if item.isKind(of: UITextField.self) {
            let txtItem = item as! UITextField
            txtItem.text = ""
        }
    })
}
```

**UPDATE** as @vacawama suggested,

```
@IBAction func buttontapped(_ sender: Any) {
    for case let txtItem as UITextField in self.view.subviews {
        txtItem.text = ""
    }
}
```

**Assumption**: All textfields are subviews of `self.view` directly. if textfields are subview of other `customview`, you should use that `customview` instead of `self.view`

Comment: This is awesome answer.upVoted!

Comment: @AbecedarioPoint thank you so much

Comment: `for case let txtItem as UITextField in self.view.subviews { txtItem.text = "" }`

Comment: @vacawama thank you, let me update my answer

Comment: In either case, OP might have to substitute another view for `self.view` if the `UITextField`s are subviews of another view (like a `UIScrollView` or `UIStackView`).

Comment: @vacawama yes you are right

Answer (score 1):

For **Objective C**

```
for (id view in [self.view subviews])                                              
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])                                       
    {
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)view;
        textField.text = @"";
    }
 }
```